# How to get asana workspaceID?

Tags: asana

Previously if I request app.asana.com/api/1.0/workspaces into a browser (after I had logged into Asana) it was returning all of my workspace ID's.
But currently it is not working and shows the error :- "{"errors":[{"message":"Not Authorized"}]}".
Is there any other solutions to get my asana workspace IDs?

Thank You,

Answer (score 1):

(I work at Asana.) We're sorry for the inconvenience - this was a security hole and we had to close it, as we wrote on our [API updates feed](http://developer.asana.com/api-updates/). If you're writing an app for others to use, Oauth is the most appropriate and secure way to access the users' data. If you're writing a simple script, you can use your API key. This can be done through a browser, but by using JavaScript and not just making requests in the browser location bar.

Comment: Please have a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50754112/how-to-attach-a-file-to-asana-task-through-api